# how to call a method in another method with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, instance-methods

I want to call selenium_parse method in parse_list method, but it seems just to skip it even though I make a break point in selenium_parse while debugging. Does anyone know how to call this? I am using Pycharm in Win10.

```py
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = ''
    allowed_domains = ['']
    start_urls = ['']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        super(Spider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_list)

    def parse_list(self, response):
        special_list_urls = response.css(
            '#SpecialsSlideBox > div.row-fluid.mrow-fluid > div > ul > li> a::attr(href)').extract()
        special_list_names = response.css(
            '#SpecialsSlideBox > div.row-fluid.mrow-fluid > div > ul > li> a::text').extract()

        dictionary = dict(zip(special_list_names, special_list_urls))
        for u in dictionary:
            target_url =  dictionary[u]
            *****self.selenium_parse(category, target_url)*****

    def selenium_parse(self, category,target_url):
        self.driver.get(target_url + '&page=1')
```

Comment: Most probably `dictionary` is empty, so the loop is not executing after that, and because of that selenium_parse is not getting called.

Comment: I agree the selenium_parse is not getting called, but the 'dictionary' is fine. The loop alse works well. @Stack

Comment: Please, fix the indentation of your code. Also, mind that using Selenium with Scrapy without scrapy-selenium is prone to errors due to Scrapy’s Twisted-based asynchronous nature. See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#using-a-headless-browser